# What are the scientific journals dedicated to artificial general intelligence?

Tags: agi, research, cognitive-science, academia, neuroscience

Apart from [Journal of Artificial General Intelligence](https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/jagi/jagi-overview.xml) (a peer-reviewed open-access academic journal, owned by the [Artificial General Intelligence Society (AGIS)](http://www.agi-society.org/)), are there any other journals (or [proceedings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conference_proceeding)) completely (or partially) dedicated to *artificial **general** intelligence*?

If you want to share a journal that is only partially dedicated to the topic, please, provide details about the relevant subcategory or examples of papers on AGI that were published in such a journal. So, a paper that talks about e.g. an RL technique (that *only* claims that the idea could be useful for AGI) is not really what I am looking for. I am looking for journals where people publish papers, reviews or surveys that develop or present theories and implementations of AGI systems. It's possible that these journals are more associated with the cognitive science or neuroscience communities and fields.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the journal **Advances in Cognitive Systems**. According to [their website](http://www.cogsys.org/home)

> [Advances in Cognitive Systems (ISSN 2324-8416)](http://www.cogsys.org/journal) publishes research articles, review papers, and essays on the computational study of **human-level intelligence**, **integrated intelligent systems**, **cognitive architectures**, and related topics. Research on cognitive systems is distinguished by a focus on high-level cognition, reliance on rich, structured representations, a systems-level perspective, use of heuristics to handle complexity, and incorporation of insights about human thinking. Advances in Cognitive Systems reviews submissions within approximately three months and publishes accepted papers on the journal Web site immediately upon receipt of final versions. Articles are distributed freely over the internet by the Cognitive Systems Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

The Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers (IEEE) recently announced a new **"IEEE Transaction on Artificial Intelligence**".  Although the topics listed do not specifically mention AGI they do not limit it.  I think this will be an interesting journal to keep an eye on as there could be some interesting AGI papers.  Below is from their [web page](https://cis.ieee.org/publications/ieee-transactions-on-artificial-intelligence):

> Welcome to the page for the IEEE Transactions on Artificial Intelligence (IEEE TAI). IEEE has established the new journal our community has been waiting for to publish our work on Artificial Intelligence! The submission site for manuscripts opens on April 1, 2020, and the inaugural issue is set to publish August 2020. Don’t miss out on this opportunity and join the community of authors who started already preparing their papers for the IEEE TAI! In one month, you will be able to submit your paper. It is time to prepare your best piece of work for IEEE TAI to increase your visibility in the international AI community and to be among the first authors to publish in IEEE TAI.

There is also the [**IEEE Transactions on Cognitive and Developmental Systems (TCDS)**](https://cis.ieee.org/publications/t-cognitive-and-developmental-systems) which is not strictly AGI but publishes topics that pertain to AGI.

> The IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON COGNITIVE AND DEVELOPMENTAL SYSTEMS (TCDS) focuses on advances in the study of development and cognition in natural (humans, animals) and artificial (robots, agents) systems. It welcomes contributions from multiple related disciplines including cognitive systems, cognitive robotics, developmental and epigenetic robotics, autonomous and evolutionary robotics, social structures, multi-agent and artificial life systems, computational neuroscience, and developmental psychology. Articles on theoretical, computational, application-oriented, and experimental studies as well as reviews in these areas are considered.

> TCDS is co-sponsored by the Computational Intelligence Society, the Robotics and Automation Society, and the Consumer Electronics Society. TCDS is technically co-sponsored by the Computer Society.

Comment: Note that I am asking about "artificial **general** intelligence" (i.e. journals dedicated to human-level intelligence or strong AI).

Comment: I added thinking that it may end up being a source of good AGI content.  Something to watch.  Only time will tell.

Comment: I also added the Transactions on Cognitive and Developmental Systems which has some similar topics to Advances in Cognitive Systems.

Comment: Maybe just keep the info about the second journal/publisher? The first one seems, from the quoted description, to be related to AI in general and not AGI.