# Are there any conferences dedicated to artificial general intelligence?

Tags: agi, research, academia

Similarly to [What are the scientific journals dedicated to artificial general intelligence?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/20411/2444), are there any conferences dedicated to artificial **general** intelligence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several conferences dedicated to AGI or human-level intelligence, such as

- [AGI Conferences](http://agi-conf.org/) (organized by [AGI society](http://www.agi-society.org/))
- [Biologically Inspired Cognitive Architectures](https://bicasociety.org/meetings/) (organized by [BICA Society](https://bicasociety.org/))
- [Advances in Cognitive Systems](http://www.cogsys.org/home)
- [IEEE Task Force on Towards Human-like Intelligence](http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/%7Emandziuk/cis_tf_thli/?page=activities)

The conferences focus on topics such as cognitive architectures, autonomy, creativity, lifelong learning, and formal models of general intelligence. There are also journals associated with these conferences (see [[1](https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/jagi/jagi-overview.xml)], [[2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/biologically-inspired-cognitive-architectures)], [[3](http://www.cogsys.org/journal)]). If you want to know more about them, I suggest that you go to their websites.

Comment: In the past, there was also [this symposium](https://www.aaai.org/Press/Reports/Symposia/Fall/fs-04-01.php) and [this track](https://www.aaai.org/Conferences/AAAI/2011/aaai11iicall.php).